# mat stepper should not collapse inactive states

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using mat stepper , by default it collapse all the in active states,but i don't want it, I want to display inactive states to expanded mode also.

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper [linear]="isLinear">
 <mat-step *ngFor="let currentUserInteraction of 
currentUserInteractions" [stepControl]="currentUserInteraction.key">
 <ng-template matStepLabel>
     {{currentUserInteraction.name}}
 </ng-template>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>

currentUserInteractions = [
{name: 'first', key: 'firstStep'},
{name: 'second', key: 'secondStep'},
{name: 'third', key: 'thirdStep'},
{name: 'fourth', key: 'fourthStep'},
];
```

Comment: go with this url and check `Optional step` there is example with formGroup https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: I read it, but can't see suitable example

Answer (score 0):

I think it is default behavior to collapse the completed/inactive steps and should not be changed.

If you really want to change this you could try to override the default Angular Material CSS with something like this (add this in your `styles.css`):

```
.mat-vertical-stepper-content {
  visibility: visible !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

All completed/inactive steps have their `height` set to `0px` and their `visibility` set to `hidden`, the above CSS reverts this for all `mat-step`. Changing this has the side effect that the Angular Material animation of the `mat-step` becomes slightly broken and a bit jumpy when you click it. See stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-fgsvgm?file=styles.scss).

Comment: Can you disable the click for that stepper, i think that would solve the jumpy result

Comment: and when we click a particular panel,its corresponding stepper should get active, because it want to change the color of stepper icon on selection of expansion panles